# Json POST body gets truncated sometimes on server - IIS 10.0 ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-core, iis

I have an endpoint in one of my controllers with this signature:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Purchase([FromBody]PurchaseModel purchase)
```

Running a simple request to it with a matching Json body, sometimes purchase comes out as null (as it can't be parsed) and sometimes it works out fine.

After debugging and testing with Postman, I noticed that the Json in the POST request body sometimes gets truncated on the server side, seemingly at random.
Same request exactly, just pressing "Submit" again and again with different results...

Some more specific information:

- The Json body size is around 2KB and gets truncated to around 1KB (when it does).
- I have just updated my project to ASP.NET Core 3.0, and previously on 2.2 it wasn't happening on the same server.
- I am using NewtonsoftJson for Json parsing.
- The server is running IIS 10.0 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Is there any setting you know that can cause this? In IIS configuration, Json parser, ASP.NET Core?
Any known issue?

Comment: Could you please help confirm below info to help reproduce the issue : 1. Can you please check request/response using fiddler to compare the working and not working request. 2.Since your application is host on AWS Elastic Beanstalk , you can also try to log on server side , either log in asp.net core Logging middleware or aws provided logging service 3. Do you change the configuration after migrating to .net 3.0 ,also check [migration document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0) 4. Do you change the AWS configuration during migration

Comment: At last , you can try hosting your app on IIS server(not on AWS server) to check whether problem still exists .

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same trouble in ASP.NET Core 3.1, except that the requests were truncated to 16KB.
Only thing that worked for me was setting AllowSynchronousIO to true.
This can be done in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // If using Kestrel:
    services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
    });

    // If using IIS:
    services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
    });
}
```

Or, as I ended up doing it in my custom middleware, you can set it per request:

```
    var syncIOFeature = context.Features.Get<IHttpBodyControlFeature>();
    if (syncIOFeature != null)
    {
        syncIOFeature.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
    }
```